# Proper Jest configuration with React-native 0.56

Tags: react-native, babeljs, jestjs

After upgrading to react-native 0.56 I'm experiencing tons of babel reated errors on jest specs that used to run just fine.

I realize that react-native 0.56 requires babel7 and that's probably related but I don't have enough experience/understaanding in babel to figure out what I'm missing.

Some error examples:

```
 /xxx/spec/Bootstrap.test.js:6
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

another:

```
 import { rootReducer } from '../store';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

My package.json jest config is as follows:

```
 "jest": {
"preset": "react-native",
"collectCoverage": true,
"coverageReporters": [
  "cobertura",
  "lcov"
],
"coverageDirectory": "coverage",
"globals": {
  "__TEST__": true
},
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "styled-components": "<rootDir>/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.native.cjs.js"
},
"moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
  "/"
],
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
],
"setupFiles": [
  "jest-localstorage-mock",
  "./node_modules/appcenter/test/AppCenterMock.js",
  "./node_modules/appcenter-analytics/test/AppCenterAnalyticsMock.js",
  "./node_modules/appcenter-crashes/test/AppCenterCrashesMock.js"
]
```

},

.babelrc is defined as follows:

```
   {
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
    },
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
    }
  }
}
```

I also have the following devdependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
"babel-eslint": "~8.2.5",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "~6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
"babel-preset-expo": "~4.0.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.1",
"babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
```

I've tried several approaches but couldn't progress much.

Besides the jest environment, the application runs fine.

Comment: I am having this same issue. You are not alone.

Comment: @nathanhayfield if it helps I've "workarounded" it by letting both Babel6 and Babel7 configurations at the package.json. 
For my jest unit tests I've set my old Babel6 configuration and for anything else Babel7's react-native preset

Comment: thanks that is a good idea

Comment: Which versions of `jest` and `babel-jest` are you using? Perhaps [this comment](https://github.com/Sneezoo/babel-7-jest#deprecated) is helpful.

Comment: @LuizHenriqueMartinsLinsRol I'm facing the same problem. Could you give me some more details about your workaround?

Comment: @luacassus if you have the chance to upgrade to 0.57 this has been solved.

Otherwise, it's not that easy to explain:

I'll try to write as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Details of the workaround I did to move on, while 0.57 wasn't ready:

Basically I had to create 2 config files:

jest-acceptance.config (with the following relevant snippets)

```
 "preset": "react-native",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/custom_b7_processor.js"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/test/.*|(\\.|/)spec)\\.js$",
```

jest-unit.config (with the following relevant snippets)

```
  "preset": "react-native",
  "testRegex": "(/test/.*|(\\.|/)test)\\.js$",
```

That custom_b7_processor, is some sort of internal code from react-native:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

/* eslint-disable */

'use strict';

const {transformSync: babelTransformSync} = require('@babel/core');
/* $FlowFixMe(>=0.54.0 site=react_native_oss) This comment suppresses an error
 * found when Flow v0.54 was deployed. To see the error delete this comment and
 * run Flow. */
const babelRegisterOnly = require('metro-babel-register');
/* $FlowFixMe(>=0.54.0 site=react_native_oss) This comment suppresses an error
 * found when Flow v0.54 was deployed. To see the error delete this comment and
 * run Flow. */
const createCacheKeyFunction = require('fbjs-scripts/jest/createCacheKeyFunction');
const generate = require('@babel/generator').default;

const nodeFiles = RegExp(
  [
    '/local-cli/',
    '/metro(?:-[^/]*)?/', // metro, metro-core, metro-source-map, metro-etc
  ].join('|'),
);
const nodeOptions = babelRegisterOnly.config([nodeFiles]);

babelRegisterOnly([]);

/* $FlowFixMe(site=react_native_oss) */
const transformer = require('metro/src/reactNativeTransformer');
module.exports = {
  process(src /*: string */, file /*: string */) {
    if (nodeFiles.test(file)) {
      // node specific transforms only
      return babelTransformSync(
        src,
        Object.assign(
          {filename: file},
          {sourceType: 'script', ...nodeOptions, ast: false},
        ),
      ).code;
    }

    const {ast} = transformer.transform({
      filename: file,
      localPath: file,
      options: {
        ast: true, // needed for open source (?) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f8d6b97140cffe8d18b2558f94570c8d1b410d5c#r28647044
        dev: true,
        inlineRequires: true,
        platform: '',
        projectRoot: '',
        retainLines: true,
        sourceType: 'unambiguous', // b7 required. detects module vs script mode
      },
      src,
      plugins: [
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping')],
        // the flow strip types plugin must go BEFORE class properties!
        // there'll be a test case that fails if you don't.
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types')],
        [
          require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),
          // use `this.foo = bar` instead of `this.defineProperty('foo', ...)`
          {loose: true},
        ],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-function-name')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-literals')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-parameters')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex')],
        [
          require('@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'),
          {strict: false, allowTopLevelThis: true},
        ],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-classes')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-spread')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')],
        [
          require('@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'),
          {loose: true}, // dont 'a'.concat('b'), just use 'a'+'b'
        ],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-for-of'), {loose: true}],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source')],
      ],
    });

    return generate(
      ast,
      {
        code: true,
        comments: false,
        compact: false,
        filename: file,
        retainLines: true,
        sourceFileName: file,
        sourceMaps: true,
      },
      src,
    ).code;
  },

  getCacheKey: createCacheKeyFunction([
    __filename,
    require.resolve('metro/src/reactNativeTransformer'),
    require.resolve('@babel/core/package.json'),
  ]),
};
```

At my .babelrc I had to include the following:

"presets": ["./node_modules/babel-preset-react-native-b6"],

That is pointing to a fork I made of the babel preset that React-native was using at 0.56-

https://github.com/lhrolim/babel-preset-react-native.

At my package.json I had te following babel dependencies

```
"babel-preset-react-native": "~5.0.2",
"babel-preset-react-native-b6": "github:lhrolim/babel-preset-react-native",
```

The test scripts I used then:

```
"test": "npm run test-acc && npm run test-unit",
"test-acc": "jest --config=jest_acceptance-config.json",
"test-unit": "jest --config=jest_unit-config.json",
```

I believe there might be some redundancies here and there, but that's what worked for me.